# CakePHP saving data in join table HABTM

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-model

CakePHP 2.4 
according to the official API docs, I can call Model::saveAll()

however , when I call the function Model::saveAll() , the browser return an error of 101(net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

instead , I can save data in a join table in a complicated way

ex:
Actor Model 
Film Model
Actor HABTM Film
I have a join table named actor_film

I can do like this

```
$this->Actor->ActorFilm->save(array("ActorFilm"=>array("actor_id"=>1,"film_id"=>2)));
```

that's so complicated

Any one can help me ?

Comment: This isn't the normal CakePHP error related to code - there's a server issue.  PDO not installed correctly, or... something.  But you're right - you should be able to call saveAll() just fine.

Comment: Resolved! that's the problem of pdo_mysql , I upgrade the php from 5.3 to 5.5 and everything is ok.by the way thnks

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3.* 
when using the method saveAll saveMany & saveAssociated will get an error of 101,

so just ungrade your php

Comment: I don't believe this to be true.  Could be proven wrong, but I believe I've made a number of CakePHP projects on servers w/ 5.3.x